# Constrain Layout top views get disturbed when keyboard gets opened guideline percent does not works

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-guideline

I tried windowSoftInputMode in manifest nothing worked the views get pushed up when the keyboard is opened I tried different approaches but none of them worked. The recycler view collapses with the edit text but it is below the guide line separator.

Image when keyboard is opened:

[image]

Image when the keyboard is not opened:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color_for_screen">
    <!--Guide line left-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_line_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/padding_margin_15" />
    <!--Guide line right-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_line_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/padding_margin_15" />
    <!--Guide line for separating image-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_line_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.17" />
    <!--Image for the top header-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guide_line_separator"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/splash_bg" />
    <!--back button image-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/step_back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_15"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_back_arrow"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_line_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <!--title for the screen-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_margin_10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_margin_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_18"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_medium"
        android:text="@string/blank"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/step_back_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <!--edit text for searching by the keyword-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_margin_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_12"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_margin_8"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:hint="@string/blank"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_margin_10"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guide_line_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_line_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label" />
    <!--recycler view for the list -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_5"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guide_line_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_line_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guide_line_separator" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove this line from rv  and then try it.
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"